# React/Redux, how to get user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i am following the [usage with React](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) Redux tutorial. Something I really don't get is how to retrieve user input.

They build a FilterLink container, whose mapDispatchToProps is

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
    }
  }
}
```

So it injects its ownProps.filter to the connected presentational component. If we go and see how this container is construced

```
const Footer = () => (
  <p>
    Show:{" "}
    <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ALL">All</FilterLink>{", "}
    <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ACTIVE">Active</FilterLink>{", "}
    <FilterLink filter="SHOW_COMPLETED">Completed</FilterLink>
  </p>
)
```

Ok, there is the "filter" property. That's clear.

Now I want to build a text filter on the same example. So first here is my presentational component

```
const TodoSearch = ({onSubmit}) => (
    <form
        onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            onSubmit()
        }}
    >
        <input placeholder="Text search" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
)
```

But when I come to write the container I don't know how to get user input

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSubmit: () => {
            dispatch(setTextSearch(????))
        }
    }
}
```

It's something I would do with jQuery $(#text).val() but... is it the best way?

Later on on the same tutorial they build a little form to add a todo to the list. Ok, let's go and see how they catch input then.

```
let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
    let input

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault()
                if (!input.value.trim()) {
                    return
                }
                dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
                input.value = ''
             }}>
                 <input ref={node => {
                     input = node
                 }} />
                 <button type="submit">
                    Add Todo
                 </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Wait, where's the magic here? Did they inject value into "input" variabile with that ref trick? Is that correct?
So if there were 20 input fields, have I to use 20 variables with 20 different refs?

Any help is appreciate, thank you

Comment: I believe it's a problem of react, rather than redux. And it's well explained in https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your submit function to the following.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSubmit: (evt) => {
            dispatch(setTextSearch(evt.target.querySelector('input').value)
        }
    }
}
```

Also,

```
const TodoSearch = ({onSubmit}) => (
    <form
        onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            onSubmit(e)
        }}
    >
        <input placeholder="Text search" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
)
```

Comment: I doesn't work, "evt" is always undefined at that point. Maybe because this is a Container component and not a Presentational component?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the users input, you can do something like this:

This demo `SearchForm`component renders an input field and a button to trigger the action.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class SearchForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleGoClick = this.handleGoClick.bind(this)
  }

  getInputValue() {
    return this.refs.input.value
  }

  handleGoClick() {
    this.props.onChange(this.getInputValue())
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref='input' />
        <button onClick={this.handleGoClick}>Go</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Notice that the input field has a **ref** value. You can retrieve the current value with `this.refs.input.value`. The `handleGoClick` method then passes this value to an action creator (that was passed into the props of the component via mapDispatchToProps).

Comment: Isn't this breaking redux philosophy? Shouldn't I retrieve the input (whether it update app's state or not) in the Container component (mapDispatchToProps) rather that in a Presentation compoent, as it is your SearchForm?

Comment: Personally I don't think it breaks redux philosophy: (1) Single source of truth (2) State is read-only (3) Changes are made with pure functions.

See [Three Principles](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html).

Maybe someone else has an opinion regarding that?

Comment: I believe it broke the first rule. As mentioned in https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html, an uncontrolled component keeps the source of truth in the DOM.

Comment: FB doesn't recommend this. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs

I personally don't like [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) either (not refs) because it is an added reference that requires you to change that reference if you move nested elements, which makes it less atomic and portable.

Answer (score 2):

I use ref to get the value of input, the handleSubmit() method is in the class, so it can get input by ref. If you want use the dispatch method, just map some props in mapDispatchToProps().

```
class AddTodo extends Component {

    handleSubmit(event) {
        let input = this.refs.input;
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return
        }
        this.props.addTodo(input.value);
        input.value = ''
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <input ref="input"/>
                    <button type="submit">
                        Add Todo
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        addTodo:(text) => {

            dispatch(addTodo(text));
        }
    }
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddTodo);
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add some explanation as to how/why your code works

Answer (score 0):

This example is here to let you better understand the react-redux way of doing things typical to react-redux, such as connect a component. It's not a tutorial to learn how to manage input state.

So, for the sake of example, they use the [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) attribute to assign to the `input` variable the `<input/>`  DOM node . Then, the value of this input DOM node is accessible via `input.value`.

They use what is called a [Uncontrolled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components), i.e a component that handle its state internally. It's handy when you don't have to deal with complex form and when the value of this particular component is not intended to be used elsewhere.

But, let's say now that this todo item text need to be saved to the server for example. The value of this input is now intended to be used elsewhere, in this case, probably in an action creator that handles the POST request. In this case, the value of the form is contained in your redux store, and you're now dealing with [Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components)