# I want to fetch data from input field react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

it's just a simple task getting me confused I want to get the data of the input field

I want to fetch it on to console

```jsx
const MessageForm = ({ handleSubmit, onSubmit }) => (
 <section className="form-container register-model-form">
   <form className="message-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

     <Input
       label="Write a message..."
       name="message"
       type="text"
     />
   </form>
 </section>
);

MessageForm.propTypes = {
 handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
 onSubmit: PropTypes.func
};

MessageForm.defaultProps = {
 handleSubmit: noop,
 onSubmit: noop
};

export default reduxForm({
 form: "MessageForm"
})(MessageForm);
```

and here is my message .jsx

```jsx
export default class Messages extends React.PureComponent {
   render() {
       return (
           <section className="page-notifications"> 
               <SubMenu/>
               <MessageForm/>
           </section>
       )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to log it on the console according to your question, pass handling function to onSubmit props like this:

```js
<Input
  label="Write a message..."
  name="message"
  type="text"
  onChange={onSubmit}
/>
```

And in the parent component:

```js
class Messages extends React.PureComponent {

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="page-notifications"> 
        <SubMenu/>
        <MessageForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
      </section>
    )
  } 
}
```

But if you mean to use redux-form you must change the Input component to Field:

```js
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const MessageForm = ({ handleSubmit, onSubmit }) => (
  <section className="form-container register-model-form">
    <form className="message-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

      <Field
        name="message"
        component="input"
        type="text"
      />
    </form>
  </section>
);
```

And change handleSubmit function to:

```js
  handleSubmit = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Arnas, its working perfectly after changing Input component to Field.

Comment: You can see complete example use of redux-form in https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/

Comment: after hitting the enter key I am getting an error - >  cannot the property "value" of undefined  in my parent container

Comment: it worked but now console.log not showing any output

Comment: it worked, I have tried it in https://codesandbox.io/embed/redux-form-simple-example-sq0vf

Comment: if it matches your question, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
<Input label="Write a message..."
    name="message"
    type="text"
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={inputValue}
/>
```

You need to pass `handleChange` and `inputValue` to your `MessageForm` component.

In the parent component do this,

```
export default class Messages extends React.PureComponent {
    handleChange = (e) =>{
       console.log(e.target.value);
    }
     render() {
         return (
             <section className="page-notifications"> 
                 <SubMenu/>
                 <MessageForm handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
             </section>
         )
     } }
```

Comment: import React from 'react';
import SubMenu from './SubMenu';
import MessageForm from './form/MessageForm';


handleChange = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target.value);
 }

export default class Messages extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <section className="page-notifications"> 
                <SubMenu/>
                <MessageForm/>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

Comment: You are writing handleChange function at wrong place , see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time it's working now as I am using redux I had to change Input component to Field

Comment: You can do the same thing using `redux` also. The way you are writing your `handleSubmit` function, same way write `handleChange` function and dispatch an action with inputValue i.e. `e.target.value`. Finally in your reducer you can change the state value.

Comment: You can also check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281957/react-redux-how-to-get-user-input

Comment: after hitting the enter key I am getting an error - > cannot the property "value" of undefined in my parent container